# Typescript react, arrays of different types problem

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hello I have a problem I have 2 arrays of different types one is array of objects, the second is an array of string. I want to map through these 2 arrays. Get the name property from the first and the just item from the second one. I wanted to check if props.items.name exists but the problem I can use the "name" property.

```
interface funcProps {
  items: ingredient[] | string[];
}

const ListBox: React.FC<funcProps> = (props) => {
  const thereIsNoItem = props.items.length === 0;
  return (
    <Box
      border="1px"
      borderColor="gray.200"
      padding="1rem"
      marginTop="1rem"
      marginBottom="1rem"
    >
      <Heading>Ingredients</Heading>
      {thereIsNoItem && <h1>No ingredients was added yet</h1>}
      {!thereIsNoItem &&
        props.items.map((item, index) => (
          <IngredientItem
            key={index}
            ingredientName={item.name || item}
            numberOfIngredient={index + 1}
          />
        ))}
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
interface funcProps {
  items: ingredient[] | string[];
}

const ListBox: React.FC<funcProps> = (props) => {
  const thereIsNoItem = props.items.length === 0;
  return (
    <Box
      border="1px"
      borderColor="gray.200"
      padding="1rem"
      marginTop="1rem"
      marginBottom="1rem"
    >
      <Heading>Ingredients</Heading>
      {thereIsNoItem && <h1>No ingredients was added yet</h1>}
      {!thereIsNoItem &&
        props.items.map((item, index) => (
          <IngredientItem
            key={index}
            ingredientName={typeof item === "object" ? item.name : item}
            numberOfIngredient={index + 1}
          />
        ))}
    </Box>
  );
};
```

It works I have done it something like this.

Comment: That solution works. but the better question is to ask yourself - why is there ambiguity about what type you accept? Union types are often a bit of a smell in Typescript, because they can indicate that you are trying to build a JS-style 'accept anything' function, which is not really the TS way of doing things.

Comment: `ingredientName={item.name ? item.name : item}` you can also do that

Comment: This sure works, but a better approach for this approach is to stick with one (here, preferably `ingredients` and use the values inside them to render/pass for eg`ingredientName`. and make other parameters as optional

Comment: @NickBailey I wanted to make a reusable component because these two things I wanted to keep in the same style. Do you think it is better to make 2 separate files, one for steps the second for ingredients? I can do a wrapper to be honest and keep it more typescript style.

Comment: no i suggest stick to this approach it look better and consize no need to provide addition props for array of string or vice versa when you can do both in one prop.

Comment: My personal recommendation would be 'always pass `[]ingredient` and in contexts where you are currently passing `[]string` build `[]ingredient` instead. That way if you component expands to need other properties on `ingredient` you can handle those updates. But again, that's a design recommendation, not a 'will this work'

Comment: @NickBailey Bailey So what you mean is that I should rebuild my ingredients object to include steps and ingridients inside it?